# Java Get Application Resource Directory

Tags: java

I am building an application which saves images to disk, and then displays the images within the GUI by reading from disk.

For testing purposes, I am saving all the images to the user's desktop.

How does Java find its directory to save to (dependent on OS)?

For example on Mac, I'd expect an application to write to ~/Library/Application Support/Application/, equalls on Windows I'd expect something like C://Program Files/Application/.

Does Java provide this functionality, or is this something that's hardcoded, or have I completely missed something here?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: I would have said the Windows equivalent of `~/Library/Application Support` would be the `APPDATA` environment variable (typically `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data` on XP, `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming` on Win 7).  `Program Files` is more like `/Applications`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "standard" place where apps are supposed to deposit their files.  This is completely OS dependent, and there's no standard API that could determine this in a platform-independent way.  It even changes depending on the OS version (Win95 vs XP, vs 7).  A Java app doesn't even need to be "installed", in the sense of copying it into `/usr/local/bin` or `C:\Program Files\...`.

You will have to write OS-specific code or ask the user where to put things.  Take a look at `System.getProperties()` and the `java.util.prefs` classes.

Comment: Just the explanation I was looking for. Thanks Jim